# Do Java carry out method after a return statement

Tags: java, return

I am just confused if a method after a return statement will be carryed out or it is just see as a variable.
Example:

```
public boolean onSystemChecked(boolean dubug){
  if(this.isActivated()) {
    return this.ActivateAction();
  } else {
    if(debug) {   
      System.out.println("[Debug] System Off!");
    } 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Will this.ActivateAction() be carried out? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: a main method to test this would be much quicker than asking here, but anyway yes it will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this.ActivateAction() be carried out?

Yes. Otherwise the method won't know what to return!

The return statement first *evaluates* the expression, then returns that value. Of course in the case of a void method with just a return statement of

```
return;
```

there's nothing to evaluate.

See section [14.17 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this.ActivateAction() be carried out?

Yes.

```
return this.ActivateAction();
```

is equivalent to

```
boolean b = this.ActivateAction();
return b;
```

> if a method after a return statement will be carryed out

`this.ActivateAction()` is NOT after return statement but **is part of return statement.**

Answer (score 1):

'return' actually returns value, not methods. So the purpose of method is to process and provide a result, only after that 'return' can return a value (value = output of this.ActivateAction())

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it will be executed. It is not after your `return` statement, rather the `return` value from that method, is going to be the `return` value of this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,`this.ActivateAction()` will be executed and answer of that method will be returned

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** `this.ActivateAction()` will be executed even if it is `recursive` method call and last result will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is the reference to current instance

so when you write

```
this.ActivateAction()
```

your are using the current instance to invoke the method , ans since your object is not null , thus the method 'ActivateAction' will be invoked.

after invocation the method executes and returns some value as per its definition .

so it doesn't matter whether you write return before it or not

```
this.ActivateAction()
```

will always use the current instance and invoke the 'ActivateAction' method and return some value.

now since it returns some value

thus

```
return this.ActivateAction()
```

only means to return that value , 'return' here has no special role .